# how to use same component twice in angular Js html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a component 'hero-detail'
Here is the component.js file code

```
angular.module('myApp.practiceComponent').component('heroDetail',{
templateUrl: 'components/practiceComponent/practiceComponent.html',
bindings: {
    resolve: '<'
}
})
```

I have created a separate module for component named myApp.practiceComponent

Here is the component template file

```
<h1>Practice Component</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="nameField">
<h1>Hi {{nameField}} </h1>
```

Now I am using this component in one of the main html file in this way

```
<p>This is the partial for view 1.</p>
<hero-detail id="component1"><hero-detail>
<hero-detail id="component2"></hero-detail>
```

But what I am getting is template code is rendered only once in browser, instead of two times.I have searched for it but haven't found any solution.Can it be that we can use only instance of component in single html page, then what will point of creating component??